# git fetch: how to ignore new branches

Tags: git

I have several remotes added in my repository. I'm only intrested in their master branches, but if I run

```
git fetch --all
```

or

```
git remote update
```

then all their branches are fetched. Is it possible to set up git, so it fetches only changes on remotes' master branches and it doesn't create any new remote-tracking branches?

Comment: Why do you mind keeping all tracking branches?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can edit `.git/config` and change

`fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

to, for example,

`fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master`

Also you can do `git fetch origin +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master` each time instead of just `git fetch`

You can create fetching script (like "gfm") to avoid inputting that string each time. This way you can use "gfm" to fetch just master and "git fetch" to fetch everything.